# Remove empty line from a multi-line string with Java

Tags: java, testing, groovy, automation, jmeter

I have a multi-line string and some empty lines between other lines. It looks like:

```
def msg = """
                AAAAAA

                BBBBBB


                CCCCCC

                DDDDDD







                EEEEEE
                TEST
                FFFFF


                GGGGGG
"""
```

I tried some regex expression with :

```
msg = msg.replaceAll('(\n\\\\s+\n)+', '')
```

Or

```
msg = msg.replaceAll('(\r?\n){2,}', '$1');
```

But nothing is good about what I'm looking...

Is it possible to remove only empty lines? to get something like that :

```
def msg = """
                    AAAAAA
                    BBBBBB
                    CCCCCC
                    DDDDDD
                    EEEEEE
                    TEST
                    FFFFF
                    GGGGGG

"""
```

Comment: Do you want to remove ALL empty lines between lines of text, or should there be one empty line between the text?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use regex `(?m)^[ \t]*\r?\n"` to remove empty lines:

```
log.info msg.replaceAll("(?m)^[ \t]*\r?\n", "");
```

To remain only 1 line use `[\\\r\\\n]+`:

```
log.info text.replaceAll("[\\\r\\\n]+", "");
```

If you want to use the value later, then assign it

```
text = text.replaceAll("[\\\r\\\n]+", "");
```

Comment: Your second suggestion would remove _all_ newlines.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes, I added extra details due to  ManLaw comment

Answer (score 3):

Groovy golf!

```
msg.split('\n')
   .findAll { it.trim() }
   .join('\n')
```

Answer (score 2):

Your current attempt seems very much on the right track, and I think the logic you want is to replace two or more newlines with just a single newline:

```
output = msg.replaceAll("(\r?\n)(?:\r?\n){1,}", "$1");
```

The trick here, to capture the actual newline type being used (`\n` for Linux or `\r\n` for Windows), is to capture a single `\r?\n` first, followed then by at least one more newline.

Comment: your answer doesn't compile, after adding `)` there's an error `token recognition error at: '1'`

Comment: Sorry, on a cell phone...the logic is correct, try it again