# Apache Poi - Java-: How to add text containing blank lines as separate paragraphs to a Word document using Apache POI?

Tags: java, javafx, apache-poi

I am unable to add text containing blank lines as separate paragraphs to a word document.

If I try to add the following text that contains 3 different paragraphs.

1. Some text here.
2. Another text here.
3. Another one here.

what I get is 1. Some text here. 2. Another text here. 3. Another one here. as if they were the same paragraph.

Is it possible to add a text containing blank lines as separate paragraphs to a Word document using Apache POI?

```
    public static void addingMyParagraphs(XWPFDocument doc, String text) throws InvalidFormatException, IOException {

        XWPFParagraph p = doc.createParagraph();
        XWPFRun run = p.createRun();

        run.setText(text);
        run.setFontFamily("Times new Roman");
    }
```

--In the method below MyText variable is a textArea variable that's part of a javaFx application.

```
    public void CreatingDocument() throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {
        String theText = myText.getText();
        addingMyParagraphs(doc, theText);

        FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("MyDocument.docx");
        doc.write(output);
        output.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: As I have understand your question, your problem is about adding paragraphs to a `XWPFDocument`. But you do no show any code which even tries that. If the code adds multiple paragraphs, then `Word` will show multiple paragraphs too.

Comment: [mcve] please (to demonstrate what you are after and how it isn't working as expected)

Comment: I added into the question the method that adds the paragraphs. For clarity the problem only happens when I add any paragraphs from the textarea. If I add it without using the textarea the paragraphs work correctly.

Comment: you did read the referenced help page, didn't you? Wondering why you don't provide what it suggests ..

Comment: Let me go through it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I created a sample Application that shows the whole code. I am rewriting my question with entire code so that it will provide more clarity. Thanks for the help.

Comment: In the code you posted in your question, in method `addingMyParagraphs`, you create a single paragraph and add **all** the text to that single paragraph. So basically, your question boils down to: _How to add text containing blank lines as separate paragraphs to a Word document using Apache POI_

Comment: I think that's accurate.  I will rephrase the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split your text into "paragraphs" and add each paragraph separately to your WORD document. This has nothing to do with JavaFX.

Here is an example that uses [text blocks](https://www.baeldung.com/java-text-blocks) to simulate the text that is entered into the [JavaFX] `TextArea`. Explanations after the code.

```java
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun;

public class PoiWord0 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = """
                1. Some text here.

                2. Another text here.
                
                3. Another one here.
                """;
        String[] paras = text.split("(?m)^[ \\t]*\\r?\\n");
        try (XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();
             FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("MyDocument.docx")) {
            for (String para : paras) {
                XWPFParagraph p = doc.createParagraph();
                XWPFRun run = p.createRun();
                run.setText(para.stripTrailing());
            }
            doc.write(output);
        }
        catch (IOException xIo) {
            xIo.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I assume that a paragraph delimiter is a blank line, so I split the text on the blank lines. This still leaves the trailing newline character in each element of the array. I use `stripTrailing()` to remove that newline.

Now I have an array of paragraphs, so I simply add a new paragraph to the [WORD] document for each array element.

Note that the above code was written using JDK 15.

The regex for splitting the text came from the SO question entitled [Remove empty line from a multi-line string with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57146506/remove-empty-line-from-a-multi-line-string-with-java)

[try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) was added in Java 7.

[stripTrailing()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#stripTrailing()) was added in JDK 11

Comment: This is perfect. I made the adjustment indicated by you and it works perfectly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The issue was not related to Javafx as you mentioned, it was related to Apache poi.

Comment: I made the following adjustment to the code and it works very well:   public static void addingMyParagraphs(XWPFDocument doc, String text) throws InvalidFormatException, IOException {
  
  String[] paras = text.split("(?m)^[ \\t]*\\r?\\n");
  
    
  for (String para : paras) {
            XWPFParagraph p = doc.createParagraph();
            XWPFRun run = p.createRun();
            run.setText(para.stripTrailing());
            run.setFontFamily("Times new Roman");

        }
  
  
 }